# Creating a complicated empty list or data frame

Tags: r, variables, empty-list

I have a variable that is a list.

```
[[1]]

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]

 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

[11,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4



[[2]]

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]

 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    3

 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [3,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    3

 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

[10,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4

[11,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    4
```

I need an empty variable which is same format as this variable.
My function will do some computation and will be put in the same location as this variable. However in the new variable I will not have 8th column.

Comment: x[,-8] does not work I think. x is list of 12 elts and each elt is a numeric( I think matrix? it does not specified but 2-d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replicate your data

```
df = list(matrix(rep(1, 88), ncol = 8), matrix(rep(1, 88), ncol = 8))
```

Remove the 8th column from all sublist

```
new_df = lapply(df, function(x) x[,-8])
```

Remove the 8th column from all sublist and replace all the 1's with NA

```
new_df = lapply(df, function(x) replace(x[,-8], x[,-8] == 1, NA))
```